# ¿Cómo instalar una aplicación del Framework Django en Cpanel a través de la herramienta señalada?

Tags: python, django, hosting, cpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les anexo la imagen que señala la herramienta a la que hago referencia, la verdad he pasado a través de una infinidad de pruebas y lectura de todo tipo de documentación y no he alcanzado ningún tipo de logro.

Comment: Revisa esta página del [Proyecto Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) y mejor sería preguntar con tu proveedor de hosting.

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema y fue respondido aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262600/c%c3%b3mo-desplegar-correctamente-una-aplicacion-django-en-un-cpanel/350418#350418