# ¿Cómo desplegar correctamente una aplicacion django en un cPanel?

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de desplegar por primera vez una aplicacion django en su version 2.2 con python 3.5 en un hosting que me contraté.

Para desplegar la app cuento con el cPanel y acceso SSH.

Estoy tratando de desplegar la aplicacion recién creada sin ningún tipo de código mío, solamente crear la app y desplegarla para aprender, pero aun así no lo logro.

Comment: Saludos si ya tienes contratado un hosting puedes pedir soporte tecnico generalmente suelen ayudar con estos temas, tambien los hosting tienen foros o blog donde indican temas como estos... para mayor detalle seria mejor que comentes que hosting tienes para ver algo de ello

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar el hosting que me contraté es hostingdelcaribe.net

Comment: saludos aqui te muestra como hacerlo: https://www.hostingdelcaribe.net/knowledgebase/139/Desplegar-Django-App.html

Answer (score 0):

Esto es complejo, pues tendrías que montar un proxy inverso más servidor de aplicaciones WSGI. Actualmente la combinación más potente es WSGI + NGINX. Además si quieres trabajar con HTTPS, que es lo ideal, tendrías que configurar los certificados correspondientes, y qué mínimo que instanciar una configuración óptima en general a nivel de seguridad y rendimiento...

Si nunca has visto estas tecnologías te va a llevar un tiempo bastante considerable, pues no es fácil dar con las configuraciones óptimas, hacer pruebas de rendimiento etc...

El servicio técnico de tu hosting te cobrará por ayudarte, no conozco ninguno que lo haga gratis.

Si te ves muy apurado puedes contactarme. Soy el director de Viomapp, nuestra plataforma está hecha en Python/Django.

Answer (score 0):

Montar una aplicación Django en CPanel es sencillo. Primero debes ir a setup Python app. Ahí vas a Create Application. En ese formulario te van aparecer varios campos:

- Python version: la version python de tu proyecto
- Application root: la dirección en donde se encuentra la raíz de tu proyecto. Ej: /home/usuario/MyProject
- Application URl: la direccion URL de tu proyecto. Si la quieres en la raíz (`ejemplo.com`) lo dejas en blanco
- Application startup file: es el nombre del fichero `wsgi.py`
- Application Entry point: Es el nombre del objeto dentro de wsgi.py. Por defecto es `application`
- Passenger log file: es el fichero donde se va a guardar los logs. Si lo dejas por defecto te crea un fichero en `/home/usuario/logs/passengar.log`
  Espero que te sirva de ayuda